# Why is my context not updating? I'm new to context api

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-context

I am trying to get my context to update with the specific values, however it isn't updating what I think is called the gloabl context.

Here is my code

```
//CONTEXT 
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';



export const UserContext = createContext();


export const UserProvider = (props) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: 'default',
    email: 'default@default.com',
    pass: 'password',
    authenticated: false
});

return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
        {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
);
}
```

```
    //Login
    function Login() {
    const [user , setUser] = useContext(UserContext) ;

    const [email, setEmail] = useState({
        value: '',
        validateOnChange: false,
        error: ''
    });

    const [password, setPassword] = useState({
        value: '',
        validateOnChange: false,
        error: ''
    });

    const [submitCalled, setSubmitCalled] = useState(false);
    const [allFieldsValidated, setAllFieldsValidated] = useState(false);





    function loginFunction() {
        var temp = {
            name: user.name, 
            email : email.value,
            password: password.value , 
            authenticated: true
        }
        setUser(temp); 
        console.log(`login function  ${user.name} email:  ${email.value} ${user.email} ${user.password} ${user.authenticated}` )

//Login.js:39 login function  default email:  Input@email.ca default@default.com undefined false
    }
// do other stuff below
```

The problem is the part right above(end of login.js), if you look you can see that after using setUser to update the user, the email doesn't change when it's called on right after. I am trying to get it to update so that I can use the name email and password throughout my app. But I can't get it to work.

```
 
    //App.js
    import logo from './logo.svg';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import Register from './Components/Register';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserProvider } from './Components/UserContext'; 
import './App.css';

function App() {

  

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <div className="App">

        <Navbar />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/home/"  exact >
              <Home/> 
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login/"  exact >
              <Login/> 
            </Route>
            <Route path="/register"  exact >
              <Register/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>

        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you for your help. Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async, therefore you will never get the current user values when you console log right after you call `setState`:

```
setUser(temp); // async, it takes some time to perform
console.log(`logging some user data ...`); // userState is not yet updated.
// this way you print a state not yet updated
```

if you want to console.log updated user data create a useEffect with dependency on user:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('some user data here')
}, [user])
```

fwiw, for a real application you should never store user sensitive data like password at the browser. you should use token or cookies for that.